# What steps do I take to integrate an (outdated) but working django application into my project?

Tags: django

I would like to integrate an [existing application](http://github.com/dz/jquerytester) someone has on github into my site. What steps do I need to take to integrate it?

Would most people just download this entire thing and throw it inside of the project root, add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and modify `urls.py`? I would imagine there are some extra steps I'd have to take to get it to work.

In addition, since it was written in Jan 09-esque, and I'm using the latest 1.2 release I would probably have to modify and add some form csrf checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no generic instructions for integrating existing application into your django project because every application is different.

Generally most of the popular apps provide README/INSTALL docs which guides you through installation and How to use app. An app without documentation & tests is risky to use unless you are ready to own it and take pain of going through source code and figuring it out.

Also I don't think the application you posted above can be integrated into your project without modifying the code. It's a project by itself and can be used in standalone mode. (Well that's what I think after looking at source code)